# Find permutation with highest organization number (OEIS A047838)

Tags: filtering, permutation

**EDIT: It turns out I misunderstood the definition of "organization number", so the below is incorrect.**

However, for every permutation I create with my definition of "organization number", I can show there's an "equivalent" permutation with the same organization number. Therefore the maximal organization number is the same, and there is a 1-to-1 function that converts between permutations that answer the correct definition of "organization number" and the incorrect definition.

As an example, my permutation `{5, 7, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6}` which has 7-5 or 2 as the first difference, 2-7 or 5 (absolute value) as the second difference, etc, can be converted to the sequence where 1 is in the 5th position (5 is the first element of my permutation), 2 is in the 7th position (7 is the second element of my permutation), and so on.

Thus, the answers below, with a little tweaking (possibly using `Ordering` or similar) suffice.

[OEIS A047838](http://oeis.org/A047838) defines the "organization number" of a permutation as:

> Define the organization number of a permutation pi_1, pi_2, ..., pi_n
>   to be the following. Start at 1, count the steps to reach 2, then the
>   steps to reach 3, etc. Add them up. Then the maximal value of the
>   organization number of any permutation of [1..n] for n = 0, 1, 2, 3,
>   ... is given by 0, 1, 3, 7, 11, 17, 23, ... (this sequence).

The phrase "organization number" appears to be nonstandard, but I'll
continue to use it in this question.

In Mathematica, the organization number of a permutation would be:

```
orgNumber[list_] := 
  Total[Table[Abs[list[[i]] - list[[i-1]]], {i,2,Length[list]}]];
```

Of course, that works for any list, not just permutations.

The OEIS link above provides a formula for the highest possible
organization number for a permutation of $n$ elements:

```
maxOrg[n_] = Floor[n^2/2]-1
```

My question: how can I find a permutation of $n$ elements whose
organization number is maximal. For $n > 1$, there will always be at
least 2 such permutations (since the reverse permutation has the same
organization number), and, from what I've seen, there are usually
several. I just want to find one of them.

For small values of $n$, you can brute force it:

```
maxPerm[n_] := Select[Permutations[Range[1,n]], orgNumber[#] == maxOrg[n] &]
```

but this gets really slow after about $n=10$.

I looked at the "first" permutation meeting this condition for each
value of $n=2$ through $n=8$ and got:

```
{1, 2}
{1, 3, 2}
{2, 4, 1, 3}
{2, 4, 1, 5, 3}
{3, 5, 1, 6, 2, 4}
{3, 5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 4}
{4, 6, 1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 5}
```

Going from an even number to an odd number seems to follow an obvious
pattern, so I correctly guessed the following for $n=9$:

```
{4, 6, 1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 5}
```

However, I couldn't find enough of a pattern to find a value for $n=10$.

In my "real world" application, $n = 44$, so brute forcing is not an option.

However, I did use:

```
t0 = Table[RandomSample[Range[44]], {i, 1, 100000}];
t1 = Max[Map[orgNumber, t0]]
```

Obviously, results will vary, but I got $t1 = 885$. Since the max
possible is 967, this is a pretty good value (and I get the
permutation(s) matching this number using Select, as above), but,
obviously, I'd prefer the true max.

Another interesting question would be: what's the distribution of
organization numbers for a given $n$.

Based on my random experimentation, the distribution appears to look
somewhat Normal, with a mean of $n^{2/3}$. I wasn't able to get a real
feeling for the standard deviation, though it appears to be about 59.6
for $n=44$.

Comment: `orgNumber[list_] := Total@Abs@Differences@list` should be much faster.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about Differences. I'll leave things as is in the code since I know the code I posted is working, and, even with this speed increase, I think large n will still be a problem.

Comment: I don't think you've interpreted this correctly. I believe the correct function for the result is `Tr@Abs@Differences@Ordering@res` where `res` is a permutation. A maximal example is then simply generated instantly via `Join[Range[2, 2 Floor[#/2], 2], {1}, 
  Range[2 Ceiling[#/2] - 1, 3, -2]] &` with argument of `n` desired. The results match OEIS.

Comment: @J42161217 pernaps, but it then has nothing to do with the OP title nor the oeis  sequence.

Comment: @ciao Yes! you are right. `Ordering@res` is the right answer.

Comment: Read the references. http://oeis.org/A047838/a047838.txt gives a permutation with maximum organisation number.

Comment: @ciao I understand. If `pos[i]` is the position in the list where the natural number i appears, what I'm looking for is `Abs[pos[2] - pos[1]] + Abs[pos[3] - pos[2]] + ... `. Is that what you're saying? Interestingly, I found this sequence after running my definition of `orgNumber` on several permutations. I'm guessing the two definitions are somehow equivalent?

Comment: @barrycarter - yes, that is equivalent to my function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...and we are done!
Solution for k=44 in 10 seconds

```
k=44;
r=Last@Select[Flatten[Table[Select[Riffle[#,-Last@IntegerPartitions[Floor[(Floor[k^2/2]-1)/2],{Floor[(k-1)/2]},b=Range[s=Floor[Floor[(Floor[k^2/2]-1)/2]/Floor[k/2]],s+2]]]&/@Reverse/@IntegerPartitions[Floor[(Floor[k^2/2]-1)/2]+1,{Ceiling[(k-1)/2]},Range[s=Floor[Floor[(Floor[k^2/2] - 1)/2]/Floor[k/2]],s+k-8]],Union[FoldList[Total[{##}]&,p,#]]==Range@k&],{p,k}],1],Union@Differences@Union[FoldList[Total[{##}]&,#[[1]],#]]=={1}&];w=FoldList[Total[{##}]&,1,r];
f=w+k-Max@w
Total@Abs@Differences@f
Floor[k^2/2]-1
```

> k=44
>
> {22,44,21,43,20,42,19,41,18,40,17,39,16,38,15,37,14,36,13,35,12,34,11,33,10,32,9,31,8,30,7,29,6,28,5,27,4,26,3,25,2,24,1,23}
>   967
>   967

This algorithm tries to find the differences-list of the result.

By examining the differences we can see that half of them are positive and half negative. Also sum of positives is equal to sum of negatives +1 and they are riffled. 
So we are trying to produce those two sets using `IntegerPartition` but we must choose as less results as possible in order for this to terminate. In order to make this work we have to "fine-tune" the variable `c` of the following algorithm 
(otherwise it will throw errors). The goal of this answer was to reach `k=44` which seemed impossible by testing permutations...
Here are the correct values in order to hit `k=50`

```
k=50;
c=15;
r=Last@Select[Flatten[Table[Select[Riffle[#,-Last@IntegerPartitions[Floor[(Floor[k^2/2]-1)/2],{Floor[(k-1)/2]},b=Range[s=Floor[Floor[(Floor[k^2/2]-1)/2]/Floor[k/2]],s+2]]]&/@Reverse/@IntegerPartitions[Floor[(Floor[k^2/2]-1)/2]+1,{Ceiling[(k-1)/2]},Range[s=Floor[Floor[(Floor[k^2/2] - 1)/2]/Floor[k/2]],s+c]],Union[FoldList[Total[{##}]&,p,#]]==Range@k&],{p,k}],1],Union@Differences@Union[FoldList[Total[{##}]&,#[[1]],#]]=={1}&];w=FoldList[Total[{##}]&,1,r];
f=w+k-Max@w
Total@Abs@Differences@f
Floor[k^2/2]-1
```

> k=50
>   {25,50,24,49,23,48,22,47,21,46,20,45,19,44,18,43,17,42,16,41,15,40,14,39,13,38,12,37,11,36,10,35,9,34,8,33,7,32,6,31,5,30,4,29,3,28,2,27,1,26}
>   1249
>   1249

Comment: Shiny! Any chance you could explain it? It looks like you don't user Permutations, but instead IntegerPartitions to find which integers add up to the magic number? And then what?

Comment: Actually I studied the differences and tried to produce differences that work. Right now I'm working on some modifications... I let you know

Comment: Wow! Would still be nice to understand the thought process, but that definitely answers the question.

Comment: Is there a copy error here? I''m not about to debug the jumble, but as is it blows up with a stream of errors under 12 and 11.3 MMA on my machine.

Comment: Read my comments to OP: I believe they have misinterpreted the OEIS entry, and generation is much simpler.

Comment: @barrycarter Actually, ciao nailed it in the comments section

Answer (score 5):

This answer just shows how to improve the speed of `orgNumber`:

```
orgNumber2[p_] := Total @ Abs @ Differences @ p
```

Comparison:

```
t0 = Table[RandomSample[Range[44]],{i,1,100000}];

t1 = Max[Map[orgNumber,t0]]; //AbsoluteTiming
t2 = Max[Map[orgNumber2, t0]]; //AbsoluteTiming

t1==t2
```

> {6.94362, Null}
>
> {0.4978, Null}
>
> True

Another almost order of magnitude increase in speed can be obtained by writing a version that works with multiple lists:

```
orgNumber3[p:{__List}] := Total[Abs @ Transpose @ Differences[Transpose@p], {2}]
```

Timing:

```
t3 = Max @ orgNumber3[t0]; //AbsoluteTiming
t1 == t2 == t3
```

> {0.070115, Null}
>
> True

**Addendum**

Using ciao's comment, producing the desired permutation is simple:

```
maxPerm[n_] := Ordering @ Join[
    Range[2, 2 Floor[n/2], 2],
    {1},
    Range[2 Ceiling[n/2] - 1, 3, -2]
]
```

For $n=44$:

```
r = maxPerm[44]; //AbsoluteTiming
r
orgNumber2[r]
```

> {0.000045, Null}
>
> {23, 1, 44, 2, 43, 3, 42, 4, 41, 5, 40, 6, 39, 7, 38, 8, 37, 9, 36, \
>   10, 35, 11, 34, 12, 33, 13, 32, 14, 31, 15, 30, 16, 29, 17, 28, 18, \
>   27, 19, 26, 20, 25, 21, 24, 22}
>
> 967

For $n = 10^6$ :

```
n = 10^6;
r = maxPerm[n]; //AbsoluteTiming
orgNumber2[r]
Floor[n^2/2] - 1
```

> {0.019479, Null}
>
> 499999999999
>
> 499999999999